# Qt C++ | how can I get the string data that is linked to the index when I click an item in a QListWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

I have this slot and I want to be able to use the string that is at the index being passed through. How can I get to it?

```
void Dialog::on_list_Favorites_2_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `QListWidget` instead of `QListView` you should also use the signal `itemClicked(QListWidgetItem*)` instead of `clicked(const QModelIndex &)`.

```
void Dialog::on_list_Favorites_2_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem* item)
{
    qDebug() << item->text();
}
```

Comment: When I do that I get errors: C2061: syntax error: identifier 'QListWidgetItem'
error: C2511: 'void Dialog::on_listWidget_Fav_1_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Dialog'

Comment: I get the same errors if I just make a new project with a list widget and create the slot "itemclicked" and try to run.

Comment: I am idiot. I needed to include QListWidgetItem in dialog.h

Answer (score 1):

You can use below function for this case.

```
QListWidgetItem * QListWidget::itemFromIndex(const QModelIndex & index) const
```

And then, the text of item can get using by `QString QListWidgetItem::text() const`

```
void Dialog::on_list_Favorites_2_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    QListWidgetItem* pItem = m_listWidget->itemFromIndex( index );
    Q_ASSERT( pItem );
    if ( pItem )
    {
        QString itemName = pItem->text();
    }
}
```